# (Sitecore Docker Setup) container sitecore-xp0-solr-1 is unhealthy

Tags: solr, sitecore-client, docker

On running `docker-compose up -d` this container always gives an error for me.

[image]

I have modified the solr port in `docker compose yml`, because with PORT 8983 another solr running in my local. When I checked logs for the particular container failure I found that still it is referring to the 8983 port. Any suggestion on resolving this error?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If we look at how Solr is defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file, we'll see that the port is set to map to `:8984` on your local machine to `:8983` on the running Solr container.

[image]

In my case, I have multiple Solr instances running on my machine from previously installed Sitecore instances.

Whenever I installed new Solr instances, avoiding using ports that were already being used for existing Solr instances was a prerequisite (eg. if I have one version of Solr running on 8983, for the new version of Solr I'd use 8984.  If I needed another version of Solr, that one would use 8985, etc).   The same applies in this case.

Because the default Sitecore 10 Docker Compose is trying to use port 8984, it must be available.

**Solution:** Check if there are multiple instances of solr running and stop instance running on the default port or change port number in docker-compose.yml

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Sumit Helaiya, Sorry If I m not clear in framing my question but I have already modified the SOLR port in docker-compose.yml to 8988 and this port is available. But still in error logs I see 8983 , So apart from docker compose .yml Do I need to change anywhere?

Comment: Check which solr sercive uses 8988 and stop that sercive and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check if your solution has the file called `docker-compose.override.yml`. The `docker-compose.override.yml` is the configuration file where you can override existing settings from `docker-compose.yml` or even add completely new services.

**How does docker-compose.override.yml work?**

When you run `docker-compose up`, it searches for a file named `docker-compose.yml` and reads all configured services, networks, volumes etc to create your Docker stack. If you also additionally have a file named `docker-compose.override.yml` this will be read as well and used as an override file to complement. It works in the following order:

1. All definitions from `docker-compose.yml` will be used
2. All definitions that are also defined in `docker-compose.override.yml` will automatically overwrite the settings from `docker-compose.yml`
3. All definitions only available in `docker-compose.override.yml` will be added additionally.

For more context use this article and compare your solution.

https://devilbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration-files/docker-compose-override-yml.html

Hope this helps.